# Como faço um relacionamento OneToMany Unidirecional com joincolumn obrigatório?

Tags: jpa-2.0

Como faço esse relacionamento ser obrigatório quando o *em.persist()* for executado?

**Não quero mapear bidirecional.**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id",referencedColumnName="ID",insertable=true, nullable=false, columnDefinition="bigint DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL")
public List<Telefone> getTelefones() {
    return telefones;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta pergunta não contem as Entidades. 
Bom, neste caso basta não não criar nenhum atributo na classe Telefone.
Conforme está no seu código, vc está dizendo que esta classe (não especificada na pergunta) possui vários telefones. Do jeito que está, já está unidirecional, caso vc não tenha declarado nenhum atributo desta classe (não especificada na pergunta) na classe Telefone.